# What kind of questions about vacation can I ask on StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, scope

It looks like I asked two questions on 20th December 2022, and both of them were closed. And then, I have tried editing my question and none of my edits worked. I feel that I have to ask some travel question about vacation. [What kind of question do I ask?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> Travel Stack Exchange is for road warriors and seasoned travelers.. If you have a question about …
> customs & border crossing, visas and other travel documents such as permits
> accommodation: camping, hostels & backpackers, guesthouses, B&B's, hotels, renting a villa on a trip
> loyalty programmes: frequent flyer points and hotel advantages
> health and safety issues related to travel
> modes of travelling: international, domestic, and public transport
> finances: budgets, costs, foreign exchange
> local geography/topography questions (i.e. is there a walking path between X and Y in city Z?)
> working while on the go (WWOOFing, volunteer travel etc) - not immigration or work visas, see below

Take a look at [the edit history of a question on another site](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/posts/36816/revisions). There also, there also it took one month for the question to be reopened.

Comment: Your last edit on the Linguistics post you linked to, was made only three days before its reopening. After that, it was edited by a moderator, who opened it immediately. The delay is not the problem, it is the result, of poor questions not being made better by the edits. Sideways is not upwards.

Comment: I have now deleted the question which was edited so many times and still below minimum quality for the site. Please take a break and come back in a while with questions that do fit the rules, in the mean time, follow the suggestions in the link in my answer here.

Comment: @Willeke Traveling is my favorite hobby. I am struggling to think of [what I can ask on StackExchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya, the questions you asked do not belong here, sorry, I did not make the rules but I do have to enforce them. It is not needed to ask here, better go to where the information is already available or a site where your questions do fit. You can see I ask very few questions myself, that is because what I would ask does not fit.

Comment: @Willeke Yes, but I am struggling to think of a question that will fit.

Comment: Forget it. Do not ask for a while. Read all currently active questions, start posting answers if you see a question where you know what to answer. Questions may come later or not at all.

Comment: You write in a comment above: "I am struggling to think of a question that will fit" - so I ask: why do you feel the need to ask a question here? Surely nobody is insisting that you do so - you're welcome to read as many existing questions & answers as you like, and if you see a question which you think you can answer, then you're welcome to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is effectively a recommendation piece with speculation on what might happen - which is not a good fit anywhere on Stack Exchange, as there are no correct answers - and when that was closed you did not try to improve it, you posted exactly the same question again, which is not useful behaviour.

When you have a question put on hold, look at the guidance and comments, and either improve the post to meet the requirements, or accept that it is not for this site. Reposting will only impact negatively - it can even incur automatic question bans!

Answer (score 4):

The rules are quite simple but rather strict.

Nothing opinion based, nothing resulting in lists, no price information as that changes to fast, nothing too personal as every user is different. And some more along those lines.

That leaves very few 'I go to ... and want information' questions possible.

To help out with that information I recently asked a question.
[How to find online touristic information, the kind we should not ask for on this site?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/178325/how-to-find-online-touristic-information-the-kind-we-should-not-ask-for-on-this)

The answers there, and the comment on the question, should help you with the kind of questions you asked.